# Material UI Autocomplete change selected value of one autocomplete when value is changed in another autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have two Autocomplete components on a form. I want to change the value of second Autocomplete when value of first Autocomplete is changed. Please see the sample code below. When value of first Autocomplete is changed I am setting "movie2" in state and passing it as value to the second Autocomplete. But second Autocomplete is not selecting the value. Any help will be much appriciated.

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Autocomplete
          id="combo-box-demo"
          value={this.state.movie1}

          options={top100Films}
          getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
          style={{ width: 300 }}
          renderInput={params => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              label="Combo box"
              variant="outlined"
              fullWidth
            />
          )}
          onChange={(event, val) => this.setState({ movie1: val, movie2: top100Films[2] })}
        />
        <Autocomplete
          id="combo-box-demo"
          value={this.state.movie2}
          options={top100Films}
          getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
          style={{ width: 300 }}
          renderInput={params => (
            <TextField
              value={this.state.movie2 ? this.state.movie2.title : ""}
              {...params}
              label="Combo box"
              variant="outlined"
              fullWidth
            />
          )}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Demo;

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and it seems you just need simply initialize state in your constructor, please try this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    movie1: null,
    movie2: null
  };
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, that works. Thanks a lot. Not sure why state needs to be initialised.

Comment: @user1566434 When the value starts as `undefined`, iMaterial-UI treats it as an “uncontrolled” input. When it starts with something other than undefined, it treats it as [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).